# How can I install SSH PHP library similar to Ubuntu's libssh2-php on Fedora28?

Tags: ssh, fedora, php

On Ubuntu there is the lib mentioned above:

```
sudo apt-get install libssh2-php
```

But where can I found it on Fedora?

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent package name on Fedora is `php-pecl-ssh2`. This conforms to the usual naming convention for packages from PECL, i.e. `php-pecl-<package name>`.

```
# dnf info php-pecl-ssh2
Last metadata expiration check: 1:59:21 ago on Sat 21 Jul 2018 10:40:54 AM CDT.
Available Packages
Name         : php-pecl-ssh2
Version      : 1.1.2
Release      : 3.fc28
Arch         : x86_64
Size         : 51 k
Source       : php-pecl-ssh2-1.1.2-3.fc28.src.rpm
Repo         : fedora
Summary      : Bindings for the libssh2 library
URL          : http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2
License      : PHP
Description  : Bindings to the libssh2 library which provide access to resources
             : (shell, remote exec, tunneling, file transfer) on a remote
             : machine using a secure cryptographic transport.
             : 
             : Documentation: http://php.net/ssh2
```